# Apollo v2 subscriptions graphql

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, subscription

I´m having troubles with subscriptions.
Actually it works fine implementing the subscription resolver as described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#subscription-filters) in this way:

```
  Subscription: {
  event_subscription:{
       subscribe: withFilter(
        () => pubsub.asyncIterator('ObjectName'),
        (payload, variables) => {
          return payload.objectName.id === variables.id
        },
      ),
  }  }
```

But I need to add some logic on the event_subscription call.
I´m trying to add a simple console.log like this

```
Subscription: {
      event_subscription:{
      console.log("TEST"),
      subscribe: withFilter(
        () => pubsub.asyncIterator('ObjectName'),
        (payload, variables) => {
          return payload.objectName.id === variables.id
        },
      ),
    }
}
```

but it doesn´t work and give me back this error:

```
{
 "error": {
    "message": "Subscription field must return Async Iterable. Received: undefined."
  }
}
```

Is it not possible to call a function inside the subscription?
How can I call a function on a subscription call?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

U need to call pubsub.publish(SOME_KEY,{
your_variables
});
In mutation commonly to execute logic. In your case SOME_KEY = 'ObjectName'

Comment: Actually I´ve managed already the publish method and it works fine.
My problem is related to the possibility to call some function  inside the event_subscription.
It seems to be not possible even to print something with a console.log before and it gives me back the error I´ve reported.
So without the console.log it works fine, with the console.log it doesn´t work.
Do you know if it exist a way to add some logic inside the event subscription?

Comment: If u use react on frontend u can use useSubscription hook with option onsubscriptiondata and execute logic there, on backend i dont think its possible.